# Sort Addresses in C Program Using Qsort

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I am trying to sort an array of pointers by the memory address:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct flist {
    int size;
    struct flist *blink;
    struct flist *flink;
} *Flist;

int compare(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    Flist a = (Flist)x;
    Flist b = (Flist)y;

    if(a < b)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {3, 1, 2, 4, 0};
    Flist b[5];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        b[a[i]] = (Flist)malloc(12);

    printf("Here is the array before sorting:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%p\n", b[i]);

    qsort(b, 5, sizeof(Flist), compare);

    printf("Here is the array after sorting:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%p\n", b[i]);
}
```

However, the program has no effect on the order of the addresses:

Here is the array before sorting:
0x759090
0x759030
0x759050
0x759010
0x759070
Here is the array after sorting:
0x759090
0x759030
0x759050
0x759010
0x759070

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a level of indirection: `qsort` sends in *addresses* of elements being sorted, not the elements themselves.

In your case, you are seeing addresses of the addresses of your `Flist` elements being passed. You need to dereference the pointers passed in after casting to `Flist*` (which is a pointer to a pointer):

```
int compare(const void *x, const void *y) {
    Flist a = *((Flist*)x);
    Flist b = *((Flist*)y);

    if(a < b)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`compare` receives the addresses of the array elements. These are of course already in sequence.

To sort by the values, you'd need to change `compare` to

```
int compare(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    Flist a = *(Flist*)x;
    Flist b = *(Flist*)y;

    if(a < b)
        return -1;
    else if (a == b)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

but since the pointers are not all pointing into the same array (or one past the end), it's technically undefined behaviour.